# Python unittest, pass argument to switch between target types

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am working on a python/cython project that involves communication with external devices. The code is covered by unit tests that can both be run against simulated hardware communication and external devices or on an actual target with connected external devices. There is a simple switch between target_mode and simulation_mode.

In the future, I would like to run unit tests regularly in simulation mode in CI each time code is pushed. I would also like to run tests on a device connected to the CI server, from time to time.

So, the simplest way to discover and run all tests is

```
python -m unittest discover -p "test_*"
```

Is there a simple way of passing an additional argument to all tests? Or how would you achieve that in a smart way without either writing own run/discovery scripts or brute-force workarounds?

Comment: Is "use an environment variable" too simplistic?